# iFrame break on enter key

Tags: javascript, iframe, wysiwyg

I have an iFrame to create a message. However, when I press enter while typing in the iFrame, it creates another div, however, I want it to create a `<br/>`. I tried using the execCommand insertBrOnReturn, but I did not get it to work. Any idea's? Thanks in advance!

The JSFiddle in stackoverflow doesn't really work, but I have an existing one at "Craz1k0ek/d869w67b/" after the default jsfiddle.net

```js
function iFrameOn() {
    richTextField.document.designMode = 'On';
    richTextField.document.body.style.fontFamily = 'Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif';
}
function iBold() {
    richTextField.document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
}
function iUnderline() {
    richTextField.document.execCommand('underline', false, null);
}
function iItalic() {
    richTextField.document.execCommand('italic', false, null);
}
function submit_form() {
    var theForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
    theForm.elements["myTextArea"].value = window.frames['richTextField'].document.body.innerHTML;
    theForm.submit();
}
```

```html
<body onload="iFrameOn()">
  <form action="" name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post">
    <p>
      Title
      <input name="title" id="title" type="text" size="80" maxlength="80">
    </p>
    <div id="wysiwyg_cp" style="padding:8px; width:700px;">
      <input type="button" onClick="iBold()" value="B">
      <input type="button" onClick="iUnderline()" value="U">
      <input type="button" onClick="iItalic()" value="I">
    </div>
    <textarea style="display:none;" name="myTextArea" id="myTextArea" cols="100" rows="14"></textarea>
    <iframe name="richTextField" id="richTextField" style="border:#000 1px solid; width:700px; height:300px;"></iframe>
    <input name="myBtn" type="button" value="Submit Data" onClick="javascript:submit_form();">
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the submit_form function as follows:

```
function submit_form() {
    remove_divs();
    var theForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
    theForm.elements["myTextArea"].value = window.frames['richTextField'].document.body.innerHTML;
    theForm.submit();
}
```

And then I added the remove_divs function which is as follows:

```
function remove_divs() {
    var frameHTML = window.frames['richTextField'].document.body.innerHTML;
    frameHTML = frameHTML
        .replace(/<div><br><\/div>/g, '')
        .replace(/<div>/g, '<p>')
        .replace(/<\/div>/g, '</p>');
    $(window.frames['richTextField'].document.body).html(frameHTML);
}
```

It replaces all the `<div><br></div>` elements with nothing and then it replaces all the `<div>` elements with `<p>` and all the `</div>` elements with `</p>`. This formats the text in the field exactly as I want.

Then I had an issue with setting the `DesignMode = 'On';` I solved that by placing extra code in the javascript file as follows:

```
window.onload = function() {
    window.frames['richTextField'].document.designMode = "On";
}
```

I also got some minor warnings on how I gained access to the richTextField, so I replaced all the `richTextField.document.execCommand` elements for `window.frames['richTextField'].document.execCommand`.

I hope this helps!